# Does 'genocide' cover mass murder of a people by sex or gender? Is there a better word?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, terminology, neologisms, disambiguation

***Genocide*** defined:

> In the present Convention, genocide means any of the following acts committed with intent to destroy, in whole or in part, a national, ethnical (sic), racial or religious group,

[United Nations](https://www.un.org/en/genocideprevention/genocide.shtml)

> : the deliberate and systematic destruction of a racial, political, or cultural group

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genocide)

---

***However, does this clearly extend to mass murder for/by gender or sex?***

All of this is prompted by a passage I saw in Stieg Larsson's English translation of his third novel in the *The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo*  series. [In Swedish called *Män som hatar kvinnor*, i.e. *Men who hate Women*] (BTW, the first time I have seen it used to apply to murder of men because of their gender.)

> The women of Anatolia took to the sword to crush invasion from the Caucasus, after ***the male soldiers were all slaughtered in  a far-reaching genocide***.

This brings to mind the [Srebrenica massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srebrenica_massacre), in which the victims were not only Muslim, but also only  men and boys of military age...

---

In Latin America, we hear  the word [****Femicidio****](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=femicidio%20en%20lati%20america) with all too often regularity. In the USA, it is sometimes called [**Femicide**.](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=femicide%20mean) , also heard with too much regularity...

However, **Homicide** is legally defined as "the deliberate and unlawful killing of one person by another; murder.".

And  these are all individual murders.

In other words, since the Latin prefix *hom* meaning "man" usually extends to all humans, ***is there another word for the massacre of only men?*** Or for that matter, ***the massacre of only women***?

(Also see [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/homicide))

---

Could we extend this to LGBTQ+ people?

***Given the present volatile political situation in most of the world, I am thinking we need to define this more clearly.***

***NB I have seen [Can "genocide" be used for the mass murder of disabled people?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/375730/can-genocide-be-used-for-the-mass-murder-of-disabled-people) and I am not sure that this answers the question.

Comment: _Genocide_ refers to any variety of mass murder. Motives are irrelevant; deaths are not.

Comment: The point about genocide is the **systematic** killing of people, any people as a group.: men, women, children, disabled, transgender, gay, etc. I really think breaking it down weakens it. Hitler killed them all, didn't he?

Comment: @Lambie The term is recent (1944) and I think still evolving...vamos a ver

Comment: @Lambie Saying that " the term genocide is not evolving" means less inclusive, in fact exclusive of groups. Was that your intent? Are you that prescriptive ? The term was coined only going back to 1944, was adopted by the ONU many years later...

Comment: Not at all. I am saying that genocide is **everyone** regardless of gender or gender identity. It doesn't matter when it was "coined"; it has always been everyone,. Hitler killed gays and gypsies and the mentally disabled. They don't get separate terms. Everyone is everyone. So today that INCLUDES anyone and everyone. including any LGBTQ+ individuals in Ukraine. There is no distinction in genocide. Believe me, genocide is inclusive, it includes everyone. Which is why the term is still valid today.

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia has an article on [Gendercide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gendercide):

> the systematic killing of members of a specific gender

It discusses male ([androcide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androcide)), female ([femicide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Femicide)) and non-binary versions. Only [femicide](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/femicide) seems to be listed in dictionaries, however, so whether these qualify as accepted terms is up to you.

Edit:

Most definitions for "*genocide*" specify the destruction of a group "in whole or in part". Targeting only one gender of a group definitely qualifies.

However, it's not clear what a "group" or "a people" signifies and if it covers, for example, all men regardless of cultural, ethnic or religious background.

Comment: Can you add anything that directly responds to the OP. ie does your answer imply that 'genocide' does not apply to just killing women, or does genocide work but your suggestions are preferred?

Comment: The UNI definition:  the deliberate and systematic destruction of a racial, political, or cultural group. So, if you are LGBTQ+ and in Ukraine, you are included because Ukraine is a cultural group.

Comment: @Lambie That's like a less-than-satisfactory  Venn diagram

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ What is it that is so difficult to understand? Genocide kills everyone. Now, femicide exists but it is one by one due to the fact of being a woman just like all the others: fratricide, regicide, sororicide etc. ad nauseum. Due to being a king, a sister etc. Genocide is not one by one: it means everyone. For the LGBTQ+, you have to find an individual word for each and leave genocide alone. None of these terms except genocide apply to everyone.

Comment: Can you point out to me  please where a group of say, just gays, have been mass murdered in modern history? gendercide means killing because of the gender but not a mass of people.

Comment: @Lambie I guess you have never heard of the [Pulse nightclub massacre?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlando_nightclub_shooting)

Comment: ...or going slightly further back; Himmler's ethnic cleansing included gays, communists,  and Jehovah's Witnesses....of all genders.

Answer (score 1):

For women, there are *[gynocide](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gynocide)* and *[gynecide](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gynecide#English)*, which have subtle differences. They also have an alternative form, *[gynecocide](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gynecocide#English).*

From Wiktionary:

> ***gynocide***:
> The killing of women and girls, especially considered as a social phenomenon.
>
> ---
>
> ***gynecide***:
> The killing of females, especially female infants.

Quotations:

> We find that millions upon millions of women have died as the victims of organized **gynocide**.
> [1976, Andrea Dworkin, Our Blood]
>
> ---
>
> So though there is nothing here to indicate any widespread **gynecide**, there does seem to be an assumption that women will be trying to have male children.
> [1997, Amy Richlin, Pliny's Brassiere]

*Androcide* (also offered in the other answer) has been added to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/androcide) ("*the mass murder of boys or men*") , but [TfD](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Androcide) claims that, legally speaking, it's just an alternate term for homicide.

---

Words like *[lesbicide](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lesbicide)* cover the killing of 'only' one individual and don't necessarily suggest the systemic, massacrous nature of genocide. I guess that means that we have to use terms like '[homophobic genocide](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22homophobic%20genocide%22&num=10&safe=active&ssui=on)' when discussing these atrocities.

---

Addressing the titular question, *Does 'genocide' cover mass murder of a people by sex or gender?*:

[OHCHR.org:](https://www.ohchr.org/sites/default/files/documents/issues/sexualorientation/cfi-report-ga77/ngos/2022-11-10/ProtectionApproaches-Annex1.docx)

> The Genocide Convention and most definitions of the crime of genocide do not include LGBTQI+ communities as possible victims.

(You may find [this](https://www.sah.aegean.gr/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/In-Fertile-Citizens.pdf) to be an interesting, if disheartening read- page 79)

As to whether genocide aimed exclusively at women is covered by the UN's definition, I'm not certain. The [Genocide of Yazidis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genocide_of_Yazidis_by_the_Islamic_State) was recognized by the UN, and it impacted *primarily* women, but many men were also killed.